# Switch Boolean on selected date and time

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, pip

I want to switch expiry boolean from false to true at given expiry_datetime

```
...
expiry = models.BooleanField(default=False)
expiry_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a property, or an annotation, and thus *remove* the `expiry` *field*, for example with:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class MyModel(models.Model):
    expiry_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    @property
    def expiry(self):
        return self.expiry_datetime is None or self.expiry_datetime <= now()
```

You can also filter on the `expiry_datetime` with:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

expired_items = MyModel.objects.filter(
    expiry_datetime__lte=Now()
)

active_items = MyModel.objects.filter(
    Q(expiry_datetime=None) | Q(expiry_datetime__gt=Now())
)
```

Comment: Thank You very much for solving my problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// monthIndex: start at 0
let boolTimeExpirationTime  = Date.now() >= new Date(2021, 5, 10, 18, 0, 0)? false : true // new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes, seconds)
```